# Why is the closest not working?

Tags: jquery

We need to select the closest and immediately previous element of a particular element.

What is the way of doing it? Have tried the [closest](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/cjkehc9p/) but it doesn't seems to be working.

```js
debugger;
$(document).load(function() {
  var header = $("#btn").prevAll(".header");
  console.log(header.innerHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class='header'>h1.header 1</h1>
<h1 class='header'>h1.header 2</h1>
<button id='btn'>
  button#btn
</button>
<h1 class='header'>h1.header 3</h1>
<h1 class='header'>h1.header 4</h1>
```

The alert should get `h1.header 2` inside it.

Comment: include all relevant code in OP

Comment: Please give me 1 minute

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? I believe most of the browsers already support the native closest function. If I am not mistaken even IE supports closest with a polyfill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.header` is sibling of target button and not its ancestor. You need to target previous sibling element and not parent element. use `.prevAll()` with `:first` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = $("#btn").prevAll(".header:first");
  alert(header.text());
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var header = $("#btn").prevAll(".header:first");
      alert(header.text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class='header'>h1.header 1</h1>
    <h1 class='header'>h1.header 2</h1>
    <button id='btn'>
      button#btn
    </button>
    <h1 class='header'>h1.header 3</h1>
    <h1 class='header'>h1.header 4</h1>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it doesn't seems to be working

Comment: because header variable is jquery object of element. check the updated answer.